# libconfig 1.4.9 compile for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, libconfig

I have a little trouble here. I know how to compile `libconfig` for linux with `./configure` file and `make`, but i have no idea how to do the same for the windows. INSTALL file doesn't say anything about compiling it on windows or cross compiling it to windows from linux. Official site (http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/) says that I can do that with Visual Studio 2008 (hell no) or gcc. But I don't know how. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've cross compiled the api from Linux for Windows using
`./configure --build x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=$PWD/bin`.

That configures the make files to use the 64 bit version of `mingw` to build.

The `--prefix=$PWD/bin` makes it so that when you type `make install` it will install to the root folder of the build under `/bin`. I did that so it wouldn't mix windows libraries in with my linux libraries.

I made the mistake of using i686 as the platform for mingw. Don't do that. It won't link to your project if you do.